# How can display a name if this name beginning with an number or letter

Tags: foreach, smarty

I Have this name ( mstreet )

how can show this name in smarty foreach if the name start with "m" like..

```
 {foreach from=$elements item=street}
  {if $street start with m}
       {$street}
  {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Is just an example. I working with smarty language

Comment: I try to find how can show the name if this is start with an standar letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `substr` variable modifier as in following code:

```
{foreach from=$elements item=street}
  {if $street|substr:0:1 eq 'm'}
       {$street}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Yes! This is a perfect answer! Thenk you

Comment: Marcin! And how can replace the mstreet to street?

Comment: @user3673602 Smarty is not for replacing original array. If you want to display street instead of mstreet in this case you can use: `{if $street eq 'mstreet'} {$street|substr:1}{/if}`